# @ModelAttribute annotated method WITH @ModelAttribute in method signature

Tags: java, spring, annotations

I was wondering if it is possible to chain @ModelAttribute methods by having an @ModelAttribute annotated, but not request mapped, method use another ModelAttribute in the method signature.
This would be in a controller.

ie

```
@ModelAttribute("attrOne")
public AttrOne getAttrOne() {
    return service.getAttOne();
}

@ModelAttribute("attrTwo")
public AttrTwo getAttrTwo(@ModelAttribute("attrOne") AttrOne attrOne){
    return anotherservice.getAttrTwo(attrOne);      
}
```

Then if there was a request mapped method that did this:

```
@RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET)
public String doSomething(@ModelAttribute("attrTwo") AttrTwo attrTwo )
```

would this work?

I seem to get a null object for AttrOne in the second annotated method... as the first annotated method is not called by the second one...

Cheers

Comment: for getAttrTwo() why would you need to pass attrOne? couldn't you just make the same service call or possibly cache the result of the service call?

Comment: more explanation: I would like to have both these in a one super class controller but override the first method in extending controllers....

Answer (score 4):

I ran into the same situation by learning from the spring documention:

> @ModelAttribute is also used at the method level *[..]*. For this usage the method signature can contain the same types as documented above for the @RequestMapping annotation.

I found [SPR-6299](https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPR-6299) which faces this problem. In the comments you can find a workaround by providing **only one** @ModelAttribute annotated method which sets the attributes into the model:

```
@ModelAttribute
public void populateModel(Model model) { 
  model.addAttribute("attrOne", getAttrOne());
  model.addAttribute("attrTwo", getAttrTwo());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

According to [SPR-6299](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-6299), this will be possible in Spring 4.1 RC1 or later.